# How to perform lag in R when there are multiple repeating rows for a group

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

Suppose I have a data frame as follows:

| date | price | company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-10-01 | 18 | A |
| 2001-10-01 | 20 | A |
| 2001-10-01 | 20 | A |
| 2001-10-01 | 20 | A |

I want to create a new variable `lagged_price` as follows:

| date | price | company | lagged_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-10-01 | 18 | A | NA |
| 2001-10-01 | 20 | A | 18 |
| 2001-10-01 | 20 | A | 18 |
| 2001-10-01 | 20 | A | 18 |

The new variable, `lagged_price`, takes the lagged value of `price` for group `company`. That is, `lagged_price` captures the price for the company on a previous `date`. Using `group_by` is problematic since it captures the value in the preceding row of the group `company`. Instead, I want to capture the lagged price on the previous date for that company. I also do not want to perform `distinct()` on the original dataset. Although that does the job in this example, I still want to keep other rows.

my failed solution:

```
out <- data %>%
group_by(company) %>%
mutate(lagged_price = lag(price))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `arrange(date)` before calculating the lagged value.

Comment: Make a copy of the dataset, use `distinct()` then `lag()`, then `left_join()` back into your original dataset to preserve the duplicated rows.

Comment: You could also `count()` by all variables to collapse duplicate rows, `lag()`, then `tidyr::uncount()` to uncollapse the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lagging before grouping gives

```
df %>% 
  mutate(lagged_price = lag(price)) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(lagged_price = lagged_price[1]) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  date       price company lagged_price
  <chr>      <int> <chr>          <int>
1 2000-10-01    18 A                 NA
2 2001-10-01    20 A                 18
3 2001-10-01    20 A                 18
4 2001-10-01    20 A                 18
```

Comment: This works for my task. Could you please explain what this exactly does? Why does lagging before grouping makes sense? and what does ```lagged_price[1]``` exactly capture? I am assuming it captures the first row of the group?

Comment: @fsure If you have a sorted group column, like you have, doing lag before grouping shifts the reference frame by one into the adjacent group. Thats exactly whats desired. Yes, subsetting with `[1]` takes the first element of the group.

Comment: How would I take the value from the lead year instead? lagged_price[-1] does not work..

Comment: @Amleto You would first `lag(date)`, then take the first element of this variable.